# Is wp3.8 / twenty fourteen's Sticky Nav & Responsive - core or theme based

Tags: navigation

I want to have a twenty fourteen like  sticky nav & responsive menu button, in my Genisis 2.0 theme.   Before I go to figure this out, is it somehow now native to 3.8 or is it theme dependant.

Casey

Comment: Try switching to a different theme. Does the behaviour change? Then it's (at least partly) theme-based.

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar navigation is entirely theme based. The admin toolbar at the top is native to WP 3.8.